# Genies' chess on a 10×10 board

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, graph-theory, checkerboard

The work of [Hearth Taxel](https://furbooru.org/images/127279) revealed some other results related to [genies' chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114135/75318). For example, there is an arrangement $A$ of pawns on a 10×10 board such that no 3×3 submatrix is empty and

- $A$ is symmetric about the main diagonal, which is all pawns
- Removing any pawn from $A$ leaves at least one empty submatrix, i.e. it is minimal
- Without the diagonal pawns, $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a [symmetric graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph), where there are automorphisms taking any vertex/edge to any other vertex/edge. In particular this implies that the row and column sums of $A$ are all equal

Can you find a solution?

Comment: Does a submatrix have to be a connected subgrid? I mean, does it have to be the intersection of three consecutive rows with three consecutive columns, or can it be the intersection of any three rows and any three columns?

Comment: @Ankoganit See the first problem for what submatrix means: ranks/files don't have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that

> The adjacency matrix of the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) (with the diagonal elements filled) would work

The first and third conditions are obviously satisfied; to see the zeroth condition

> We need to show that for any two sets of three vertices, there exists an edge between them. It's clear if these two set have a common vertex (just take the element on the diagonal); otherwise these two sets must be disjoint. It's not too hard to check cases (whether all three vertices are from a pentagon, or it splits into two from a pentagon, and one from the other one) to verify that this indeed works.

To see the second condition:

> If the said pawn is on the diagonal, corresponding a to a vertex $v$ on the "outer pentagon", take the submatrix corresponding to $\{v, p, q \}$ and $\{ v, p', q' \}$, where $p,q$ are the vertices "opposite" to $v$ in the outer pentagon, $v'$ is the vertex on the "inner pentagon" connected to $v$, and $\{ p', q' \}$ are the vertex "opposite" to $v'$ in the "inner pentagon". If it's not on the diagonal, since the Petersen graph is 3-arc transitive (in particular:  it acts transitively on the edges, so let that said pawn correspond to $\overline{vv'}$. Take $\{v, p, q \}$ and $\{v', p', q' \}$ to be the rows and columns of the submatrix.