# How useful is Marijn's Bluff?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, magic-the-gathering

[Parcly and Tori Taxel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114135/two-genies-and-their-kind-of-chess), after having wished genies' chess into existence and played around with it – noticing the link to Zarankiewicz's problem and getting an [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A350237) published in the process – decided to play *Magic: The Gathering* afterwards. While teaching each other the rules, however, they reached a position where Tori had exactly **161 cards** on her side of the battlefield.

It was now Parcly's turn, and she played a card called *Marijn's Bluff**, which read

> Your opponent indexes the cards in their side of the battlefield starting from 1 as they like. You win the game if in this ordering there are $x$ and $y$ such that cards $x,y,x+y$ all exist and are all the same colour; $x$ may equal $y$ and multi-colour/colourless cards may be taken as any single colour.

Without resorting to other MtG cards/rules, and bearing in mind that the game has five colours, must Tori lose no matter what her 161 cards are?

---

<sub>*Obviously Parcly had magically written her own text onto this card; MtG and Parcly's universe of MLPFIM are both owned by Hasbro.</sub>

Comment: That would be the most complicated card to ever exist XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> Yes, Tori must lose.  Every $5$-coloring of $\{1,\dots,161\}$ contains a monochromatic $(x,y,x+y)$.

> In fact, $161$ is the smallest such number for $5$ colors.  See https://oeis.org/A030126.

Comment: rot13(Naq urapr vg jnf pnyyrq Znevwa'f Oyhss – sbe gur bar jub cebirq vg.)